# Accessing session within session in Django Template

Tags: python, django, templates, session

This is my view code

```
def edit_previous(request):
    curr_page_id= request.session['event_id']
    request.session[curr_page_id]['ep_name'] = request.POST.get('ep_name')
    print request.session[curr_page_id]['ep_name']
return render(request,'pages/edit-info.html')
```

I need to access my session values in my template according to the current page id...

```
{% with curr_page_id = request.session.event_id %}
{{ request.session.curr_page_id.ep_name }}
{% endwith %}
{{request.session.587.ep_name}}
```

I am not able to access with block when I use the session within session..
but i am able to access it in manually. How could i access it?

my TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS has

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
# redirect to the current page
"django.core.context_processors.request",
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
'dsp.context_processors.common_content',
'dsp.context_processors.common_variables',
'inbox.context_processors.mail_variable',
```

)

Comment: Your code doesn't render any template in your view

Comment: Thanks for your comment .. this is just part of my code.. i need to access only the session values in my template. i am not able to access when i am using session value within session

Comment: Can you please provide the code that calls `render` or `render_to_response` method?

Comment: You should pass request to your render function `return render(request, 'pages/edit-info.html')`

Comment: I added it but still i am not getting my session in my template view..

Comment: What do you have in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`?

Comment: You should add `django.core.context_processors.request` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Comment: I have displayed my template_context_processors in my code

Comment: i have already added in my `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` but still i didn't get it

Comment: Django template variables don't work like that. `curr_page_id` is a literal string when you use it inside the variable lookup. But I can't understand why you are using sessions here anyway: get the value in the view and pass it to the context.

Comment: Is there any way to convert the string literals??